# Quickblox : Conflicts between ASI Http symbols and modules

Tags: ios5, asihttprequest, quickblox

I am trying to implement chat module in my app. I have referred Simple Sample code of QuickBlox API.

But when I try to register user from my app I got below error of linker.

my Code : -

```
// Create QuickBlox User entity
 QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
 user.password = _textPassword.text;
 user.login = [DicResponse valueForKey:@"User name"];
                
 // create User
 [QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
```

In my app I am already using `ASIHTTP` library. If I comment this line `[QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];` then it compiles successfully.

How to solve this conflicts ?

> ```
> duplicate symbol _isDismissing in:
>     /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dtliqcvxngqgfwgzpbvmtupglcjd/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIAuthenticationDialog.o
>     /Projects/abc/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBASIAuthenticationDialog.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _NetworkRequestErrorDomain in:
>     /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dtliqcvxngqgfwgzpbvmtupglcjd/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIHTTPRequest.o
>     /Projects/LockMEIfYouCan/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBASIHTTPRequest.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _RedirectionLimit in:
>     /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dtliqcvxngqgfwgzpbvmtupglcjd/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIHTTPRequest.o
>
>     /Projects/app/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox(QBASIHTTPRequest.o)
> ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use latest [QuickBlox iOS SDK version 1.4](https://github.com/downloads/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/QuickBlox_iOS_Framework_v.1.4.zip) or just download from [QuickBlox iOS SDK GitHub page](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk)